# How to auto increment composite key Id only when a specific condition is met?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, sql-server-2012

I have a code first MVC 5 project with a model that has a composite key:

```
public class XYZ
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //For reporting purposes.
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int Version { get; set; }
```

I am trying to keep track of the version of each `XZY`. I only want the `Id` attribute to increment when the version is 1, otherwise add a new row to the table with the same Id number and incremented version.

I'm not sure how to get the Id to auto increment ONLY when a new `XYZ` is created and NOT a new version. Any suggestions on how to go about getting the Id to auto increment only when I want a new `XYZ` and not a different version?

The purpose of the versioning is to keep track of different entry versions so that histories can be rolled back. One of my current problems is that this project is half way through and due to either poor design and/or lack of knowledge (no one had done code first web dev before) I am loath to change how the db is organized.

Useful project info: Visual Studio 2013, SQL Server 2012, ASP.Net MVC 5 C#.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `IDENTITY` columns for that. You can use a `SEQUENCE` together with manual T-SQL code but that is tedious and the sequence is non-transacted.

Probably, you'll have to abandon the auto-generated identity scheme entirely and generate the ID yourself through querying the previous max ID. Note, that this will introduce a contention point that becomes relevant with many concurrent inserts.

Other schemes for manual ID generation are available. Might be worth doing some research.

Comment: So if I insist on doing it my way I'd need to lock the table to obtain an ID and then insert the new row? Unfortunately I'm boxed in with this for now due to circumstances beyond my control.

Comment: You do not need to lock the table but you need to lock the key-range that starts with the last row. This effectively serializes all operations that act on the last part of the table. If you can tolerate ID gaps there are ways around that. Worth some research. I'd search for "SQL Server ID generation strategies".